# ListViewの要素をタップした際に、ListViewを持つActivityに遷移したい

Tags: java, android

FirstActivityのListViewをタップすると、また別のListViewを持ったSecondViewに遷移させます。設定画面のように実装したいと考えています。

遷移後のSecondActivityにある次のコードでエラーが出ます:

```
setContentView(listView2);
```

エラーメッセージはこちらです:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

activity_first.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context="com.example.hoge.hogehoge.Activity.FirstActivity">
      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

FirstActivity.java

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    final ListView listView1 = new ListView(this);
    setContentView(listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    adapter.add("A"));
    adapter.add("B");
    adapter.add("C");

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

activity_second.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context="com.example.hoge.hogehoge.Activity.SecondActivity">
      <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="@string/text"/>
     <ListView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/listView2" />
     <Button
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/button"
         android:onClick="onClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    ListView listView2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view2);
    setContentView(listView2);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    adapter.add("D");
    adapter.add("E");
    adapter.add("F");

    listVIew2.setAdapter(adapter);       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findViewById で listView2 を layout の中から拾い出しているので、さらに重ねて set する必要はないはずです。

つまり、

```
setContentView(listView2);
```

この処理は不要なはずです。エラーについてはこれで解消されるはずです。

> TextView以外表示されません

`layout_height`を`match_parent`にしているためではないかと思います。3 つとも、`wrap_content`にしてみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！エラーは出なくなりました。ですがSecondActivityにはTextView, ListView, Buttonが置いてありますが、TextView以外表示されません。

Comment: @Shangri-La 回答を更新しました